# Python Question Relating to Finding Anagram from Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, dictionary-comprehension, anagram

I am struggling with this project that I am working on.

Edit: I want the program to find 2 words from the dictionary that are the anagram of the input word(s). The way I wanted to approach this program is by using counter(input()) and then looping through the dictionary content twice (finding first word anagram then the next). The loop would take every word from the dictionary, counter(that word) and see if it is <= counter(input word). Once the program finds first anagram, it adds that word to candidate and proceeds to second loop to find the second word.

To put to simple words, if I input a word (or a phrase), I would like the program to run through a dictionary text file (which I have saved) and find two words from the dictionary that becomes anagram to my input. For instance, if I input "dormitory" the program output should be "dirty room" and if input "a gentleman", output "elegant man". Here is what I have done so far:

```
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter

my_dictionary = open(Path.home() / 'dictionary.txt')
my_words = my_dictionary.read().strip().split('\n')
my_dictionary.close()

letter_number = 0
my_word = []

print('Please type in your phrase:')
word = input()
word = word.replace(" ","")
word_map = Counter(word.lower())

for a_word in my_words:
    test = ''
    candidate = ''
    test_word = Counter(a_word.lower())
    for letter in test_word:
        if test_word[letter] <= word_map[letter]:
            test += letter
    if Counter(test) == test_word:
        candidate += a_word.lower()
        for a_word in my_words:
            test = ''
            test_word = Counter(a_word.lower())
            for letter in test_word:
                if test_word[letter] <= word_map[letter]:
                    test += letter
            if Counter(test) == test_word:
                candidate += a_word.lower()
            if Counter(candidate) == word_map:
                my_word.append(candidate)

print(my_word)
```

For some reason I am getting nothing from the output.

1. I cannot get any result after I put my input.
2. I also have tried to use del. command for getting rid of the word counter of first word from dictionary then proceed to find a second word from the dictionary but that didn't work either.

In summary, there must be some wrong place in the codes that flaws the program to not give any output.

Please help me figure out my mistake and error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should mention which specific issue you ran into

Comment: edit your question to paste the error traceback

Comment: Ok Will do. Sorry I am now to this so still trying to figure options out :(

Comment: Start by trying to explain, in plain English words, your intended algorithmic approach to the problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Did so man. Let me know if I need more clarifications. Sorry for the inconvenience :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code can be optimized as follows:

```py
# script.py
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter

filename = 'dictionary.txt'
my_words = Path.home().joinpath(filename).read_text().strip().splitlines()

word = input('Please type in your phrase:\n').replace(" ","")
word_counter = Counter(word.lower())

def parse(my_words=my_words):
    matches = []
    for a_word in my_words:       
        a_word_counter = Counter(a_word.lower())
        if all(c <= word_counter[w] for c in a_word_counter.values()):
             matches.append(a_word)
    return matches

def exactly_parse(my_words=my_words):
    return [w for w in my_words if Counter(w) == word_counter]
    
my_word = parse()
print(my_word)
```

Let's say content of dictionary.txt:

```sh
$ cat dictionary.txt
how
are
you
fine
thanks
```

- input word is `how`
- What's the expected output? how

```sh
$ python script.py
Please type in your phrase:
how
['how']

$ python script.py
Please type in your phrase:
thanksyou
['you', 'thanks']
```

Comment: Thanks for simplifying the codes. To elaborate, from the word input, I would find counter for the input (word_map). Then I would take every word from dictionary and see its counter, compare if it is part of word-Map. Then, I would find another word from the dictionary, do the same and would want the counter of the two words to equal that of input. This way, I would get 2 word anagram. If i put the word dormitory in, I would expect the first part of loop to find dirty then to find room as the counter of two words equal that of input. (2 word anagram found for the input)

Comment: You'd better show the content of 'dictionary.txt', and give an example of input and expected output.

Comment: Hey man, I did so in the question. To list it here again, examples are, input: dormitory then output: dirty + room or input: a gentleman and output: elegant + man. Also, for the dictionary. txt, its just a dictionary in text file. List of all words in a txt file.

Comment: If you assume the content of dict.txt to that, if you input how you should get how because there are no other words that contain "h""o""w" right? Also, if you input "thanksyou" then you should get "thanks"and "you" because they are included in the dictionary and anagram of the word "thanksyou".

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the work. I do see how it is concise than mine. However, I was wondering if you can help me with this one (and last) part: Is there a way to make this program find exact anagrams. To be specific, if input is thanksyou, it has 1 T, 1 H, 1A, 1N, ... and 1U. The output should be word or words that include(s) exactly same letter components (making them exact anagrams)

Comment: Use the function `exactly_parse`

Comment: I'm still trying to figure this out but thanks so much man. This is huge help.